# Is there any way to get the output in debug mode, not to be truncated?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is there any way to get the output in debug mode, not to be truncated?
example value: `results: (Vector((1.6292068494294654e-07, -1.0, 0.0)), Vector((1.6292068494294654e-07, -1.0, 0.0)))`
is truncated below...
[image]

Comment: what if you use the expand `>` button on that line

Comment: it's still truncated.  I can 'copy value' and paste it, but i'd like to avoid those steps, if i could.

Comment: then create an issue to request a setting for `watchVariableDisplay: full | truncate`

Comment: Thanks... I created a feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/167474